# How do I get the Paypal Express Checkout to display the trial amount, not the regular amount when creating recurring payment profiles?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, trial

How do I get the Paypal Express Checkout to display the trial amount, not the regular amount when creating recurring payment profiles?

We have implemnted a coupon system, allowing the user to claim, say a discount of 10% for 3 months. All works fine, the correct discounted amounts are charged for the 3 months, then the full regular fee takes over, however at the PayPal checkout page, there is no mention of the discounted trail period. The users may believe they're not getting the discount.

Once the profile is created, and the user logs into their PayPal account, full discounted detail;s show up.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer but what I ended up doing was to add a note to the name of the item, say your subscription name is 'Magazine' then send to paypal the name as

Magazine (one week trial)
OR
Magazine (10% off first three months)